# Given X ~ N(0,1).Find P(X>0) and P(X<0)

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

All I understand here is that it is a question of binomial deviation where the particular case is of standard deviation i.e ( I familiarise it with the bell curve.an image has been attached.) .I am aware that there is a table to calculate for particular values of X.But what about the following two cases?[image: the bell curve I was talking about.]

... consider me as 'not so well versed person' in this topic and explain me as simplified as you could. Thank you.
P.s if someone could post a detailed solutions,you could leave the understanding part on me..
Just in case this question feels incomplete or has some ambiguity please let me know.

Comment: You've drawn the picture for P(X<z) for some positive z.  Did you try drawing the corresponding picture for 0?  The answer will smack you in the face.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(z)dz=1$ and $f(z)=f(-z)$?